# Problem with gps.encode() using TinyGPS library

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, tinygps, tft

First, see the schematics (attached). [image: schematics]

The GPS is working properly when I write code only for reading data from it as below:

```
//Connect with pin 18 and 19
#include <TinyGPS.h>
//long   lat,lon; // create variable for latitude and longitude object
float lat,lon; //notice herewhy lon is not ina   get same same
TinyGPS gps; // create gps 

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(57600); // connect serial    for TFT
Serial.println("The GPS Received Signal:");
Serial1.begin(9600); // connect gps sensor    for GPS
  }
 
void loop(){
    
    
    
    while(Serial1.available()){ // check for gps data

      delay(1000);

        Serial.println( Serial1.read());
   
    if(gps.encode(Serial1.read()))// encode gps data
    { 
    gps.f_get_position(&lat,&lon); // get latitude and longitude

    Serial.print("Position: ");
    
    //Latitude
    Serial.print("Latitude: ");
    Serial.print(lat,6);   
    Serial.print(",");
    
    //Longitude
    Serial.print("Longitude: ");
    Serial.println(lon,6); 
    
   }
  }
}
```

In the above code, when I print serial data coming from GPS, it is like 44,65,46,48,57,44,13,10,84.... and then gps.encode() function encodes it properly and returns true and ultimately I get correct values of longitude and latitude.

Now, the problem is when I use that same code along with my TFT code, it does not read serial data correctly and prints like 0,44,0,57,0,10,0,44,0,50,0,44... and the gps.encode() function always returns false. and I am unable to get any values of longitude and latitude.

Here is the complete code of TFT + GPS:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>      // this is needed even tho we aren't using it
#include "Adafruit_GFX.h"
#include "Adafruit_ILI9341.h"
#include <Adafruit_STMPE610.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <TinyGPS.h>

TinyGPS gps; // create gps 

void Draw_Compass_Rose();
void display_item(int x, int y, String token, int txt_colour, int txt_size);
void arrow(int x2, int y2, int x1, int y1, int alength, int awidth, int colour);

// For the Adafruit TFT shield, these are the default.
#define TFT_DC 9
#define TFT_CS 10

// Use hardware SPI (on Uno, #13, #12, #11) and the above for CS/DC
Adafruit_ILI9341 tft = Adafruit_ILI9341(TFT_CS, TFT_DC);

// The STMPE610 uses hardware SPI on the shield, and #8
#define STMPE_CS 8
Adafruit_STMPE610 ts = Adafruit_STMPE610(STMPE_CS);

// This is calibration data for the raw touch data to the screen coordinates
#define TS_MINX 150
#define TS_MINY 130
#define TS_MAXX 3800
#define TS_MAXY 4000

/*** UI details */
#define BUTTON_X 40
#define BUTTON_Y 140
#define BUTTON_W 60
#define BUTTON_H 30
#define BUTTON_SPACING_X 20
#define BUTTON_SPACING_Y 10
#define BUTTON_TEXTSIZE 2

/* Back Button details */
#define BACK_BUTTON_X 40
#define BACK_BUTTON_Y 40

#define BLACK   0x0000
#define BLUE    0x001F
#define RED     0xF800
#define GREEN   0x07E0
#define CYAN    0x07FF
#define MAGENTA 0xF81F
#define YELLOW  0xFFE0
#define WHITE   0xFFFF

// text box where numbers go,position the text box/rectangle
#define TEXT_X 10
#define TEXT_Y 10
#define TEXT_X1 10
#define TEXT_Y1 50
#define TEXT_X2 10
#define TEXT_Y2 90
#define TEXT_W 220
#define TEXT_H 30
#define TEXT_TSIZE 3
#define TEXT_TCOLOR ILI9341_MAGENTA
// the data (phone #) we store in the textfield
#define TEXT_LEN 12
char latitude[TEXT_LEN+1] = "";
char longitude[TEXT_LEN+1] = "";
uint8_t latitude_i=0;
uint8_t longitude_i=0;
char STATUS_X;
char STATUS_Y;
float lat = 0.0;
float lon = 0.0;
float AZMTH = 0.0;
float add;

const int centreX  = 160;
const int centreY  = 120;
const int diameter = 100;
int last_dx, last_dy, dx, dy;

// 0 -> Keypad    1 -> Compass
unsigned int page_state = 0;

// 0 -> latitude     1 -> longitude
unsigned int cursor_state = 0;

/* create 15 buttons, in classic candybar phone style */
char buttonlabels[15][5] = {"ENT", "CLR", "NEXT", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", ".", ">"};
uint16_t buttoncolors[15] = {ILI9341_DARKGREEN, ILI9341_DARKGREY, ILI9341_RED, 
                             ILI9341_BLUE, ILI9341_BLUE, ILI9341_BLUE, 
                             ILI9341_BLUE, ILI9341_BLUE, ILI9341_BLUE, 
                             ILI9341_BLUE, ILI9341_BLUE, ILI9341_BLUE,
                             ILI9341_BLUE, ILI9341_BLUE, ILI9341_ORANGE};
Adafruit_GFX_Button buttons[15];

char backButtonLable[1][5] = {"Back"};
uint16_t backButtonColors[1] = {ILI9341_DARKGREEN};
Adafruit_GFX_Button backButton[1];

// Print something in the mini status bar with either flashstring
void status(const __FlashStringHelper *msg) {
  tft.fillRect(STATUS_X, STATUS_Y, 240, 8, ILI9341_BLACK);
  tft.setCursor(STATUS_X, STATUS_Y);
  tft.setTextColor(ILI9341_WHITE);
  tft.setTextSize(1);//font size on top of white box
  tft.print(msg);
}
// or charstring
void status(char *msg) {
  tft.fillRect(STATUS_X, STATUS_Y, 240, 8, ILI9341_BLACK);
  tft.setCursor(STATUS_X, STATUS_Y);
  tft.setTextColor(ILI9341_WHITE);
  tft.setTextSize(1);//font size on top of white box
  tft.print(msg);
}

void setup() {
Serial.begin(57600); // connect serial
Serial.println("The GPS Received Signal:");
Serial1.begin(9600); // connect gps sensor
  
  // clear the screen
  tft.begin();
  tft.fillScreen(ILI9341_BLACK);
  tft.setTextColor(ILI9341_MAGENTA);
  tft.print("      WELCOME TO AZIMUTH SYSTEM");
  // eep touchscreen not found?
  if (!ts.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Couldn't start touchscreen controller");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println("Touchscreen started");

  // create buttons
  for (uint8_t row=0; row<5; row++) {
    for (uint8_t col=0; col<3; col++) {
      buttons[col + row*3].initButton(&tft, BUTTON_X+col*(BUTTON_W+BUTTON_SPACING_X), 
                 BUTTON_Y+row*(BUTTON_H+BUTTON_SPACING_Y),    // x, y, w, h, outline, fill, text
                  BUTTON_W, BUTTON_H, ILI9341_WHITE, buttoncolors[col+row*3], ILI9341_WHITE,
                  buttonlabels[col + row*3], BUTTON_TEXTSIZE); 
      buttons[col + row*3].drawButton();
    }
  }
  
  // create 'text field'
  tft.drawRect(TEXT_X, TEXT_Y, TEXT_W, TEXT_H, ILI9341_WHITE);
  tft.drawRect(TEXT_X1, TEXT_Y1, TEXT_W, TEXT_H, ILI9341_WHITE);
  tft.drawRect(TEXT_X2, TEXT_Y2, TEXT_W, TEXT_H, ILI9341_WHITE);
  
  tft.setCursor(TEXT_X+2, TEXT_Y+10);
  tft.setTextColor(TEXT_TCOLOR, ILI9341_BLACK);
  tft.setTextSize(2);//font size inside white box
  tft.print(" LAT:");

  tft.setCursor(TEXT_X1 + 2, TEXT_Y1+10);
  tft.setTextColor(TEXT_TCOLOR, ILI9341_BLACK);
  tft.setTextSize(2);//font size inside white box
  tft.print(" LONG:");

  tft.setCursor(TEXT_X2 + 2, TEXT_Y2+10);
  tft.setTextColor(TEXT_TCOLOR, ILI9341_BLACK);
  tft.setTextSize(2);//font size inside white box
  tft.print(" AZMTH:");
}

void loop() {
  
  TS_Point p;
  
  
  /*
  while(Serial1.available()){ // check for gps data    //this has issue it is not written correctly
  if(gps.encode(Serial1.read()))// encode gps data
   Serial.print("Position: ");
  }
  */
  
  
  //lets try starts


  while(Serial1.available()){

    delay(1000);

      Serial.println( Serial1.read());

    bool res = gps.encode(Serial1.read());

    Serial.println(res);
    
    if(res)// encode gps data       //here is the problem lies    <<<<<<<<<===================================== it always return 0 thats why not working
    {
      gps.f_get_position(&lat,&lon); // get latitude and longitude


       Serial.print("Position: ");
    
    //Latitude
    Serial.print("Latitude: ");
    Serial.print(lat,6);   
    Serial.print(",");
    
    //Longitude
    Serial.print("Longitude: ");
    Serial.println(lon,6); 
      
      }
        
  
    

   

    }
    
    




  //lets try ends
  
  
  
  if (ts.bufferSize()) {
    p = ts.getPoint(); 
  } else {
    // this is our way of tracking touch 'release'!
    p.x = p.y = p.z = -1;
  }
  
  // Scale from ~0->4000 to tft.width using the calibration #'s
  if (p.z != -1) {
    p.x = map(p.x, TS_MINX, TS_MAXX, 0, tft.width());
    p.y = map(p.y, TS_MINY, TS_MAXY, 0, tft.height());
    Serial.print("("); Serial.print(p.x); Serial.print(", "); 
    Serial.print(p.y); Serial.print(", "); 
    Serial.print(p.z); Serial.println(") ");
  }

  switch(page_state){
    case 0: // Means Keypad
  // go thru all the buttons, checking if they were pressed
  for (uint8_t b=0; b<15; b++) {
    if (buttons[b].contains(p.x, p.y)) {
      //Serial.print("Pressing: "); Serial.println(b);
      buttons[b].press(true);  // tell the button it is pressed
    } else {
      buttons[b].press(false);  // tell the button it is NOT pressed
    }
  }

  // now we can ask the buttons if their state has changed
  for (uint8_t b=0; b<15; b++) {
    if (buttons[b].justReleased()) {
      // Serial.print("Released: "); Serial.println(b);
      buttons[b].drawButton();  // draw normal
    }
    
    if (buttons[b].justPressed()) {
        buttons[b].drawButton(true);  // draw invert!    

        // ENT Button was clicked
        if (b == 0){
          lon = atof(longitude);
          lat = atof(latitude);
          status(F("  Searching and laser start rotating"));
          Serial.println("Searching ");
          Serial.print("Latitude : ");
          Serial.println(String(lat));
          Serial.print("longitude : ");
          Serial.println(String(lon));
          Serial.print("lat + lon = ");
          AZMTH=lat+lon;
          Serial.println(AZMTH);

            // just add this part in this location
          //----- AND REPLACE THE VALUE -----
          tft.setCursor(TEXT_X2 + 90, TEXT_Y2+10);
              tft.setTextColor(TEXT_TCOLOR, ILI9341_BLACK);
              tft.setTextSize(2);//font size inside white box
              tft.print(AZMTH);
              Serial.print(AZMTH);

        }
        
        // CLR Button was clicked
        else if (b == 1) {
          switch(cursor_state){
            case 0:
              if (latitude > 0) {
                latitude_i--;
                latitude[latitude_i] = ' ';
              }
              break;

            case 1:
              if (longitude > 0) {
                longitude_i--;
                longitude[longitude_i] = ' ';
              }
              break;
          }
        }

        // NEXT Button was clicked
        else if (b == 2){
          page_state = 1;
          tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
          latitude[0]=0x00;
          latitude_i=0;
          longitude[0]=0x00;
          longitude_i=0;
          cursor_state = 0;
                           
          tft.setRotation(1);
          Draw_Compass_Rose();
            double angle= 270; //use heading from compass
            dx = (diameter * cos((angle-90)*3.14/180)) + centreX;    // calculate X position
            dy = (diameter * sin((angle-90)*3.14/180)) + centreY;    // calculate Y position
            arrow(last_dx,last_dy, centreX, centreY, 20, 20,BLACK);  // Erase last arrow     
            arrow(dx,dy, centreX, centreY, 20, 20,CYAN);             // Draw arrow in new position
            last_dx = dx;
            last_dy = dy;
          delay(25);
          tft.setRotation(0);

          }          
 
        // '>' Button was clicked 
        else if (b == 14){
          /* Toggle between latitude and longitude */
          if (cursor_state == 0){
            cursor_state = 1;
          } else if (cursor_state == 1){
            cursor_state = 0;
          }
        }
        
        // if a numberpad button, append the relevant # to the textfield
        else if (b >= 3) {
          switch(cursor_state){
            case 0:
              if (latitude_i < TEXT_LEN) {
                latitude[latitude_i] = buttonlabels[b][0];
                latitude_i++;
                latitude[latitude_i] = 0; // zero terminate
                //fona.playDTMF(buttonlabels[b][0]);
              }
              break;
            case 1:
              if (longitude_i < TEXT_LEN) {
                longitude[longitude_i] = buttonlabels[b][0];
                longitude_i++;
                longitude[longitude_i] = 0; // zero terminate
                //fona.playDTMF(buttonlabels[b][0]);
              }
              break;
          }
          
        }

       Serial.println("Value of cursor_state: ");    //where is written touch screen started? you there????
       Serial.print(cursor_state);

      switch(cursor_state){   //This condition is always false

            Serial.print("If successfully comes here then this line should print");  //This means 
        
            case 0:
              // update the current latitude
              tft.setCursor(TEXT_X + 90, TEXT_Y+10);//set position of text when user key in the lat angle
              tft.setTextColor(TEXT_TCOLOR, ILI9341_BLACK);
              tft.setTextSize(2);//font size inside white box
              Serial.print(latitude);
             // if (gps.f_get_position(&lat,&lon))    //<- this condition is wrong
              {
             // tft.print(String(gps.f_get_position(&lat));
              gps.f_get_position(&lat,&lon);
              Serial.println("Latitude on Serial: ");
               
              Serial.print(lat, 6);  
              }
              break;

              // update the current longitude
            case 1:
              tft.setCursor(TEXT_X1 + 90, TEXT_Y1+10);//set position of text when user key in the long angle
              tft.setTextColor(TEXT_TCOLOR, ILI9341_BLACK);
              tft.setTextSize(2);//font size inside white box
              Serial.print(longitude);
             // if (gps.f_get_position(&lat,&lon))
              {
             // tft.print(String(gps.f_get_position(&lon));
              gps.f_get_position(&lat,&lon);
              Serial.println("Longitude on Serial: ");
              Serial.print(lon, 6);  
              }
              break;
          }
        
    } 
//        
      delay(50); // UI debouncing

     }
   }
}

void display_item(int x, int y, String token, int txt_colour, int txt_size) {
    tft.setCursor(x, y);
    tft.setTextColor(txt_colour);
    tft.setTextSize(txt_size);
    tft.print(token);
    tft.setTextSize(2); // Back to default text size
}

void arrow(int x2, int y2, int x1, int y1, int alength, int awidth, int colour) {
  float distance;
  int dx, dy, x2o,y2o,x3,y3,x4,y4,k;
    distance = sqrt(pow((x1 - x2),2) + pow((y1 - y2), 2));
    dx = x2 + (x1 - x2) * alength / distance;
    dy = y2 + (y1 - y2) * alength / distance;
    k = awidth / alength;
    x2o = x2 - dx;
    y2o = dy - y2;
    x3 = y2o * k + dx;
    y3 = x2o * k + dy;
    x4 = dx - y2o * k;
    y4 = dy - x2o * k;
    tft.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, colour);
    tft.drawLine(x1, y1, dx, dy, colour);
    tft.drawLine(x3, y3, x4, y4, colour);
    tft.drawLine(x3, y3, x2, y2, colour);
    tft.drawLine(x2, y2, x4, y4, colour);
}
void Draw_Compass_Rose(){
  int dxo, dyo, dxi, dyi;           
    tft.drawCircle(centreX,centreY,diameter,YELLOW);  // Draw compass circle
  for (float i = 0; i <360; i = i + 22.5) {
    dxo = diameter * cos((i-90)*3.14/180);
    dyo = diameter * sin((i-90)*3.14/180);
    dxi = dxo * 0.9;
    dyi = dyo * 0.9;
    tft.drawLine(dxi+centreX,dyi+centreY,dxo+centreX,dyo+centreY,YELLOW);  
  }
    display_item((centreX-5),(centreY-85),"N",RED,2);
    display_item((centreX-5),(centreY+70),"S",RED,2);
    display_item((centreX+80),(centreY-5),"E",RED,2);
    display_item((centreX-85),(centreY-5),"W",RED,2);
}
```

Please help me. I shall be very thankful to the person who helps me.

Comment: i fail to understand how anyone would identify the problem to be the gps.encode()  function, when the problem is clearly the data from the GPS module being corrupted by the presence of the TFT module and/or the TFT program ... determine if the problem is caused by the presence of the TFT module alone, or if it caused by software ... try to narrow down what part of the program causes the fail

Comment: @jsotola Okay. but I mentioned earlier that if I run GPS standalone then it works properly but when it is used with TFT it does not give proper serial data.I don't know where is the problem. I am stuck on it for weeks now

Comment: Added: the TFT is connected when I run the GPS code (and excluding TFT code) and GPS works properly

Comment: now add simple `hello world` TFT code

Comment: Do you realise that you're discarding every other byte from the GPS? `Serial.println(Serial1.read());` reads a byte, displays it, then you never get that byte back again.

Comment: @Majenko yes I know that, it was for testing purpose only.

Comment: @Majenko any suggestions what could be the problem?

Comment: And that "testing" breaks everything. Ditch that. Or put the read value into a variable so you can use it twice. At the moment you're seeing, instead of "Hello world" just "el od"